# How to fetch data from database into textbox

Tags: angularjs, angular

Can anyone help me how to fetch data from database into the text boxes? I am able to save anyway but i want to fetch what i have saved back into the same text boxes respectively.

//form

```
     <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">

          <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(companylisting)"  #companylsiting="ngForm" >

 <div class="form-group">
              <label for="first_name"> Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="company.name" name="first_name" required>
            </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

//service

```
updateClient(id){
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      let body = JSON.stringify(id);
      return this.http.put('http://example.com' + id, body, headers)
          .map((res: Response) => res.json());


  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not leaving the active route you would just requery the object that is bound to your form.  In this case 'company' is the object in your component that is bound to your form.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" [(ngModel)]="company.name" name="first_name" required>
```

You would need to requery that object (through a service) and the form will automatically rebind all the controls.

Comment: So if i clearly understand you, it has got to do with the backend?

Comment: Yes, If your intention is to rebind the template to the values currently stored in the database, you would need to refetch the values through a service call and set the result of that service call to your local variable 'company'.